# Creating a simple release calendar in Magento

Tags: php, magento, calendar

I'm trying to create a simple release calendar in a Magento CMS page. Many of the products in my store will be available for pre-order and I'd like to be able to list the release date and the product name with a link to the Magento product page sorted by the nearest release date to the most distant.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom block (inside of a custom module) to draw the list of products:

1. On the page linked follow steps 1-4, creating a ReleaseCalendar block instead of Menu, and using your own company's identifier and your own module name rather than Gravitywell_Example.

   - http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-creating-your-own-custom-block-in-magento
2. Add a getReleasesCollection function to your block.
3. Inside of that function you'll want to get and return a collection of products, filter it by products with a release date greater than the current date then order the collection by release date.

   - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento
   - `$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();` will get you started with a collection of all products.  Don't forget to apply a visibility filter as well.
4. Format the collection into a calendar in your template file.  You can use $this->getReleasesCollection() to get the collection you created in steps 2 and 3 into the frontend.

Once you have created the module your CMS page will be able to include the block using something like this:

`{{block type="yourmodule/releasecalendar" name="releasecalendar" template="yourmodule/releasecalendar.phtml"}}`

In the long run you'll want to get a better understanding of how you can use models (and possibly controllers) for something like this, but this solution is much more developer friendly until you're more experienced with magento.

Comment: I've got everything working except I'm unable to include the block in my CMS page.

I'm using:
`{{block type="lsc/releasecalendar" name="calendar" template="lsc/calendar.phtml"}}`

I am able to get it to work using a bit of php but this is not ideal for my situation.
`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('lscreleasecalendar/calendar')->setTemplate('lsc/calendar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you able to see the products and their release dates? Are you getting an error, is the {{...}} code not rendering (showing the code on the frontend), or is nothing appearing?

Comment: I've edited my first comment to make my problem a little clearer. Nothing at all is appearing.

Comment: Can you post the config.xml of your module on https://gist.github.com/ or another similar source hosting site.  Are you trying to put the block code in your phtml template, or in the content section of a CMS page?

Comment: I was adding the block code into the content section of the cms page. I'll upload the code shortly, I'm just about to head home from work. Thanks for your assistance Matt, you've been a big help.

Comment: I've uploaded the config.xml to github. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5718978

Comment: I've actually got it figured out, I should have been using:
`{{block type="lscreleasecalendar/calendar" name="lscreleasecalendar" template="lsc/calendar.phtml"}}`

Comment: Great!  If you want to take it a step further you can package your module for magento connect then you'll be able to really easily use it in other magento installs without any code editing.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/creating_magento_connect_extension_package